# Angular - ERROR ReferenceError: config is not defined

Tags: angular, authentication, authorization

I'm following a tutorial of Angular 7 authentication and authorization from [here.](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/11/22/angular-7-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example)

I've added all the required files and there's no error during ng serve as well. 
The tutorial also requires

```
declare var config: any;
```

to be added to typings.d.ts file. By default there was no typings.d.ts file in my src directory so I manually created typings.d.ts and added the required declaration there. 
Config is being used in 2 services respectively

In Authentication.service.ts

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/users/authenticate`, { username, password })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                if (user && user.token) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                    this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                }

                return user;
            }));
```

and in user.service.ts

```
 getAll() {
        return this.http.get<User[]>(`${config.apiUrl}/users`);
    }

    getById(id: number) {
        return this.http.get<User>(`${config.apiUrl}/users/${id}`);
    }
```

After adding the declaration in typings.d.ts file the error from compiler goes away but when I run the application and try to sign in I get the following error on console:

**ERROR ReferenceError: config is not defined**

Detailed log:

```
ERROR ReferenceError: config is not defined
    at AuthenticationService.push../src/app/auth/_services/authentication.service.ts.AuthenticationService.login (authentication.service.ts:23)
    at LoginComponent.push../src/app/login/login.component.ts.LoginComponent.onSubmit (login.component.ts:51)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (LoginComponent.html:6)
    at handleEvent (core.js:10251)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11344)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:11047)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:7710)
    at core.js:9190
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:3563)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:195)
```

**I've tried similar questions but they do not state any help. Any suggestions to fix or work around config in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thank you.**

Entire code for authentication.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from '../_models';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationService {
    private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
    public currentUser: Observable<User>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
        this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
    }

    public get currentUserValue(): User {
        return this.currentUserSubject.value;
    }

    login(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/users/authenticate`, { username, password })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                if (user && user.token) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                    this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                }

                return user;
            }));
    }

    logout() {
        // remove user from local storage to log user out
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
        this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
    }
}
```

Entire code for users.service.ts

```
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from '../_models';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getAll() {
        return this.http.get<User[]>(`${config.apiUrl}/users`);
    }

    getById(id: number) {
        return this.http.get<User>(`${config.apiUrl}/users/${id}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi ..can you post all yours service ts code?

Comment: Done. Please check.

Comment: Have you added the webpack.DefinePlugin entry to your webpack config?

Comment: @Sergio  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            // global app config object
            config: JSON.stringify({
                apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4200'
            })
        })
Added to webpack.config.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry why don't use a different way .. like this:

put your config.apiUrl in a `constant or BETTER in your enviroment.ts file` .. so you can `change the api url for different enviroment as you need` ..

somthing like:

environment/environment.ts

```
export const environment = {

  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/',

     // <-- HERE PUT OTHER CONFIG THAT CAN CHANGE FROM EENVIROMENT 
};
```

then import it in yours ts file (like service or any where you need it) .. like:

```
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from '../_models';
import { environment } from '../environment/environment';


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getAll() {
        return this.http.get<User[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/users`);
    }

    getById(id: number) {
        return this.http.get<User>(`${environment.apiUrl}/users/${id}`);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you ...

If you still want a config constant .. cfreate it in the same way as enviroment does

Comment: Didn't think of this approach. Thank You. Works like a charm.

Comment: happy it helped you